# Can a spinning frisbee have lift in still air?

Tags: aerodynamics, navier-stokes, lift

Frisbees normally generate lift because their "wing" is moving through air,
so what would happen if I just get the frisbee spinning without pushing its
center of mass forward?  Assume there is no gravity so there is no falling
"parachute effect".

Let's define a frisbee as a 2D cross section which is rotated about the y axis,
so that the object has complete rotational symmetry about the y axis.  The spin
for this experiment is then applied about the y axis and lift is the y component
of acceleration.  (If there were no rotational symmetry, one could obviously
generate lift by using a "helicopter blade", or by simply adding some 45-degree
"elevator tabs" to the bottom of a normal frisbee.)

Comment: By assuming a frisbee as a 2D cross section, do we need to neglect the curvature near the circumference?

Comment: No - That curvature is allowed.  As I tried to write in the question, a frisbee is a 3D object with the same 2D cross-section for any rotation angle from which you view it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Rusian. It will produce lift because the skin friction drag of the spinning frisbee will cause the air to move outward from its center as a result of centrifugal force. When the air reaches the lower lip of the frisbee it will be directed downward by the lip, and thereby create lift.

Comment: @Ruslan said there is no lift, so did you mean to write "I disagree with Ruslan"?

Comment: Good explanation.  Back-of-the-envelope calculations then tell me that the fastest human throws of the lightest frisbees (if somehow thrown exactly at the same speed as a strong trailing wind, such that there is no relative airspeed) generate lift of about 1% of earth's gravity for about the first second of flight (spin decays quickly for a light frisbee), so we simply don't notice this.  Underwater experiments might be an interesting confirmation...

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a frisbee hanging still (no rotation) in an endless sea of air (no gravity). Obviously, the frisbee will not move. When the frisbee is rotating though, there will develop a rotating motion of air inside the inner confines of the frisbee. This results in a vertex of air moving away from the frisbee (from the non-flat side). As a result, the flat side will move with a steady velocity (air friction). If the frisbee were just a flat cylinder (that is, symmetric), it wouldn't move.

Answer (score 0):

A frisbee simply spinning with its center of mass at rest will generate no lift. This is easy to see simply by considering that it's not pushing any air downwards. It's the horizontal motion through the air which generates lift. Spin is only needed to stabilize the disc, so that it doesn't wobble or flip over.

Comment: It could be pushing a little air downwards, how do you know?

Comment: @bobuhito if it pushed a little downwards, it would also push a little upwards, so there'd be no net effect.

Comment: I'd say it's not symmetric (top of frisbee and bottom of frisbee are different), so can't agree so easily.

Comment: @bobuhito if you consider the disc frictionless, then, to the air molecules hitting the disc, it's as good as fully resting: they don't notice that the surface is in motion because there's no force that makes the molecules change direction—other than the normal force, which simply reflects the molecules in a way independent of angular speed.

Comment: Consider the streamlines over a spinning but otherwise stationary frisbee. They are all planar circles. There is no lift-generating component to the flow.

Comment: The "planar circle" picture is not a proof that the deeper circles within the protected air inside the frisbee (the bottom side) have the same pressure as the shallow circles above the frisbee. @Ruslan It's not frictionless, there's viscosity and a boundary layer where molecules are moving (exactly as needed to explain lift when the frisbee is moving, so I can't simplify it as you want).

Comment: Though I'd prefer more proof, I think this answer is correct for laminar flow, but feel that a frisbee could be designed to generate turbulence on one side (top or bottom) before the other...could such turbulence then create lift?

Answer (score 0):

A real toy frisbee is a little round wing, as long as said wing doesn't exceed its critical angle of attack and air continues to pass over it, it will generate lift!

Answer (score -1):

Simple. A frisbee without rotation just drops to the ground. But a @Ruskan said, so does a rotating one. It takes rotation for stability and motion relative to the air for a frisbee to generate lift.

Comment: A frisbee with rotation also just drops to the ground.